# SAS only read the first information of the following space delimited dataset

Tags: sas, dataset, read-write, raw

I am trying to read the following txt dataset in SAS but unfortunely, I only get half of the dataset information in my final table.
The file is

```
Kreil Professional M 823421 Natan Expert M 234 Silvio Beginner M 2342 Steven Unexperienced M 2343
Anton Expert M 76575 Sophia Professional F 79 Cecilia Unexperienced F 78585 Michael Professional M 23424
Kelly Expert F 43212 Kevin Beginner M 23532 Sarah Beginner F 23523 Emmanual Beginner M 234542
Andre Unexperienced M 3242 Valerie Expert F 2342 Jesper Professional M 2141 Michael Unexperienced M 4141
Benoit Unexperienced M 3425 Nicolas Expert M 765757 Alice Beginner F 57858 Madelaine Expert F 2412
```

I used the following code:

```
INFILE "path/File/data.txt";

INPUT Name $ Experience $ Sex $ Salary $ ;
run;
 
 
Proc print data=Data;

proc sort data=data OUT=Data_n;
BY DESCENDING Salary Name Experience  Sex Salary;
RUN;

proc print data=Data_n;
```

As a result, I got:

```
       1    Alex    Professional    M   37884
       2    Kreil   Professional    M   823421
       3    Anton   Expert          M   76575
       4    Kelly   Expert          F   43212
       5    Andre   Unexperience    M   3242
       6    Benoit  Unexperience    M   3425
```

The information contained in the other half of each row is missing. How can I solve this please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the Double Trailing @ Line-Hold Specifier. This tells SAS to keep reading fields on the same line without moving to the next line. It looks like your input file is formatted as per the example shown in the SAS help here: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/basess/n068wqvbjnndvjn17mqpoxdj7te7.htm

Your new code would have an input statement like this:

```
INPUT Name $ Experience $ Sex $ Salary $ @@;
```

Each time SAS reaches the @@, if it is not at the end of a line, it will go back and try to pick up `Name`, `Experience`, `Sex` and `Salary` again, from the same line.